# Issues with prepared statements / bindValue

Tags: php, sqlite

So I have the following code, mostly adapted from examples from [php.net's SQLite3 prepare statement page](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php).

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( accesstoken, authed, ckey, staff) VALUES (':password', 'false', ':ckey' ,'true');");
$stmt->bindValue(':ckey',$_POST["ckey"]);
$hashedpw = password_hash($veri_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt->bindValue(':password',$hashedpw);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

I figured it would work, however when I review the database manually I see this:

`:ckey, :password, false, false` as the row that was inserted.
I can't seem to fix it either, I tried removing the quotes around it and threw an error instead. I swapped the quote types and either got an undefined column or  some other error.

Here is a snip of the code right before that:

```
$stmt  = $db->prepare("select * from `users` WHERE ckey = :ckey");
$stmt->bindValue(":ckey",$_POST["ckey"]);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

That works just fine however it is a select query rather than a insert and it only has one value to bind. I've looked at about least 10-15 related questions and still can't solve it, one suggested using `'` instead of `"` but that didn't solve it another suggested using `?` instead of `:ckey` and that left me with question marks inside of my database (how fitting) and I still have not been able to resolve it.

Comment: try removing the single quotes around `:password` and `:ckey` in the query itself.

Comment: It still persists, I just reviewed my server logs for hints and I'm going to reinstall my test server and test my code again as I feel something is wrong and someone else seems to have had the same issue.

Comment: Alright, after the reinstall my code is slightly broken however now it does work properly after removing the quotes.. I think my install was corrupted or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the quotes change

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( accesstoken, authed, ckey, staff) VALUES (':password', 'false', ':ckey' ,'true');");
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` ( accesstoken, authed, ckey, staff) VALUES (:password, 0, :ckey ,1)");
```

Credit to [Cfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119326/)